# Flutter Conflict: geolocator: ^5.1.4+1 and google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+7 generate dependency conflict

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

Currently I'm doing a Flutter application witch uses:

```
  geolocator: ^5.1.4+1
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+7
```

When I declare both dependencies in "pubspec.yaml" it get a conflict

`"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

- What went wrong:

  `Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.`

  > Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks' has different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (17.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution"
- I've tryied also by editing gradle.properties with:

```
   android.useAndroidX=true
   android.enableJetifier=true
```

And in `"app/build.gradle"` added the dependencies as classpath and/or api as needed:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks`

Is anyone facing same issue? In case you solved it, what have you done to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, though using `google_maps_flutter0.5.21+8`.
I added for every error message the following line to `android/app/build.gradle` under dependencies. Look then like the following:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
}
```

Hope that helps. If there's a better way please tell. No flutter expert so far.